# XSLT if matching all XML tag contents

Tags: xml, xslt

**Problem** : Given an xml file, get the value of content/id tag with value 'sam' using xslt

**Issue**: All the values matching the same path getting selected. Both brian and sam.

(I wondered the select should select the first match and shouldn't loop like for-each utility provided in xslt)

**xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Primary>
  <PID>Tech1</PID>
  <Version>1234</Version>
  <AData>
      <Id>widnows</Id>
 </AData>
 <BData>
   <Content>
      <Id>brian</Id>
   </Content>
   <Content>
      <Id>sam</Id>
   </Content>
 </BData>
</Primary>`
```

**xslt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
  <xsl:template match="/Primary">
    <xsl:variable name="var" select="'sam'" />
     <xsl:apply-templates select="BData/Content">
         <xsl:if test="Id='sam'">
         <xsl:value-of select="Id"/>
         </xsl:if>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "*get the value of content/id tag with value 'sam' using xslt*" The value of `content/id` tag with value `'sam'` is `'sam'`. You don't need any XSLT to know that.

Comment: This was the preliminary selection for further processing. Kept the problem statement simple so as not to make it look complex.

Answer (score 1):

You currently have an `xsl:if` statement as a child of `xsl:apply-templates` which is not allowed in XSLT. If you only want to select `Content` elements with an `Id` value of "sam", you can put the condition in the select attribute of `apply-templates`, like so

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="BData/Content[Id='sam']" />
```

Try something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
  <xsl:template match="/Primary">
     <xsl:variable name="var" select="'sam'" />
     <xsl:apply-templates select="BData/Content[Id=$var]" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Content">
      <xsl:value-of select="Id" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: The expression within the square brackets does not have to be just equals, it can be any valid expression, for example, if you wanted only `Content` elements whose `Id` started with "sam" or "bob", you would do this:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="BData/Content[starts-with(Id, 'sam') or starts-with(Id, 'bob')]" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped. But it isn't about direct match. Can I add string methods like starts_with() and logical operators instead of just [Id= $var]. Basically anything that is passed to 'test' in a tag.

Comment: Well, if you want an answer to a question, first you must ask the question, and the question you asked was how to "get the value of content/id tag with value 'sam'".... Having said that, in reply to you comment, you can indeed use more complex expressions here. I've amended my answer to show an example.